# Get custom HTTP header (Cookie) using SOAP web service client in Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, cookies, soap, netbeans

I am using the standard web service client in Netbeans. The SOAP server includes a Cookie as a HTTP header. How do I access this header/cookie from the client code?

I assume one method involves using a MessageHandler. I have added a Web Service **Message Handler**, and I have tried modifying the `public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext messageContext)` method, but I cant figure how to grab an HTTP header, and not a SOAPMessage.

I know how to add a custom header in the web service client, e.g. for Authentication, but I just dont know how to get a custom header in the client:

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "Password".toCharArray());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I used was by using `getResponseContext()` to get a custom HTTP header:

```
 Map<String, Object> responseHeaders;
 responseHeaders = sourceDispatch.getResponseContext();
 Object cookie = responseHeaders.get("javax.xml.ws.http.response.headers");
```

This is nice and familiar because I had used `getRequestContext` to set a custom HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
SOAPConnection connection = IpspSOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance().createConnection();
SOAPMessage responseSoap = connection.call(requestSoap, webServiceUrl);
String[] someHeader = responseSoap.getMimeHeaders().getHeader(someHeaderName);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but could not get it working. I eventually used another solution

Comment: Do not mention it. Good luck!